# What happens when an undead character is "Taken Out"

Tags: fate, dresden-files, undead, taken-out

I tried finding this in the books, but I couldn't figure anything out.  If you have an undead character, what happens when their physical stress track is filled and they don't take a consequence?  Are they taken out like other characters?

I know that undead characters don't heal like normal characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The concept of being "taken out" in any FATE game is not a strict matter of life-death or victory-defeat. It means one specific thing:

**The player loses control of the character**. The character's fate is in the hands of the opponent. The opponent is expected to narrate how the character meets his demise, in a manner that makes sense according to what brought him down. The opponent must also declare how and if the taken-out character can recover.

So in your case, whoever took out that undead thing decides what happens to it.

YS 203 says:

> #### Getting Taken Out
>
> If the damage exceeds the character’s stress track, or occupied boxes “push” the stress off the right side of the stress track, the character is taken
> out, meaning the character has decisively lost the conflict. **His fate is in the hands of the opponent, who may decide how the character loses.** The outcome must remain within the realm of reason — very few people truly die from shame,
> so having someone die as a result of a duel of wits is unlikely, but having him embarrass himself and flee in disgrace is not unreasonable.